# Do decaying exponential signals have finite energy?

Tags: indefinite-integrals, signal-processing

> "A signal that decays exponentially has finite energy, so, it is also
>   an energy signal."
>
> *http://www.songho.ca/dsp/signal/signals.html*

---

I don't quite get how that can be true. Energy of a signal is defined as:

$$
E_s = \langle x(t),x(t)\rangle = \int_{-\infty}^\infty |x(t)|^2\,dt.
$$

According to [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integral+of+%28e%5E-2x%29%5E2+from+-infinity+to+infinity), this integral does not converge for $e^{-2x}$, so how can this qualify as a finite energy signal?

Comment: Watch out, you should integrate $e^{-2x}\mathrm dx$, not $e^{-2}\mathrm dx$

Comment: A signal that decays exponentially in both directions has finite energy. In your example the signal does not decay as you go backward in time.

Comment: They are referring to a signal that decays in only one direction

Comment: I don't see where in the link you derive that conclusion.

Comment: It is a beginner Signals and Systems course, and it would make no sense to refer to a doubly-decaying exponential there...

Comment: @M.Hassaan I address this in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Probably they mean to consider the integral starting from a particular point in time (as opposed to all the way to $-\infty$), in which case the integral is finite.

Comment: The same definition is used on the site

Answer (score 1):

Following up on the comment discussion:

Courses are written by humans, who are at times imperfect.  An expert in signal analysis might see the term "signal that decays exponentially" and immediately picture a function like $$x(t) = \begin{cases}e^{-t},& t\ge 0 \\ 0, &t < 0,\end{cases}$$
or $x(t) = e^{-|t|}$ as Ian hinted at.  This interpretation would be entirely natural to an expert because

1. they have probably seen such "decaying pulse" signals many times before;
2. it occurs in a context immediately following discussion of a single square wave pulse (which is finitely supported);
3. the alternative interpretation of a signal that grows unbounded in one direction would be a signal of infinite power and doesn't make sense in this context.

It would be very easy for such a human being, especially someone writing without feedback from an coauthor/editor/referee, to overlook the possibility that a beginner will see the term "signal that decays exponentially" and picture the function $x(t) = e^{-t}, -\infty < t < \infty$.

In short, yes, decaying exponential signals have finite energy, but $e^{-t}$ by itself is *not* a decaying exponential signal.